# Get item index within an ArrayList by passing generic params

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I need to create a method that return the index of an object in a list by comparing one of its fields.
I have 2 classs A and B with overrided `Equals()` and `HashCode()` methods like this:

Class A:

```
public class A {
 private String field1;
 private String field2;
 //getters and setters
 @Override
 public boolean equals (Object o){
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
  if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
  A that = (A) o;
  return field1.equals(that.field1);
 }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
   int result = super.hashCode();
   result = 31 * result + field1.hashCode();
   return result;
  }
}
```

Class B :

```
public class B {
 private String field1;
 private String field2;
 //getters and setters
 @Override
 public boolean equals (Object o){
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
  if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
  B that = (B) o;
  return field2.equals(that.field2);
 }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
   int result = super.hashCode();
   result = 31 * result + field2.hashCode();
   return result;
  }
}
```

In my main program I need to implement a generic method that returns the index of an item within an `ArrayList<>` of A or B.

```
private int getObjectIndexFromList(List<A or B> list, A or B param){
  int index;
  try{
    index = list.indexOf(list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(param)));
  }catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
    index = -1;
  }
  return index;
}
```

So my question is how to pass generic params for the method ?

Comment: And what is the relation between A and B ? If nothing, Interfaces are your friends.

Comment: Why do you need that method at all? Just use `list.indexOf(element)`.

Comment: @Eran  OP wants to pass only one list that satisfies both the list's signature.

Comment: @Eran like Suresh Atta told you, I need to use that method for both lists of A and B.

Comment: @SureshAtta can you explain a bit more how can I use Interface in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to compare with either `A.field1`, `A.field2`, `B.field1`, or `B.field1`?

In that case you can use a lambda to find it in the stream. Like this:

```
private <T> int getObjectIndexFromList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate){
    int index;
    try {
        index = list.indexOf(list.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .findFirst()
                .get());
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
        index = -1;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Then you just use it like this:

```
int index = getObjectIndexFromList(listOfAs, a -> a.field1.equals("foo"));
```

Using streams here isn't optimal though since you're effectively traversing the list twice and checking equality on both the parametar and the sought object. Using a list iterator that keeps track of the current index is be more efficient:

```
private <T> int getObjectIndexFromList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate){
    ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        // Get the item and it's index in the list
        int index = it.nextIndex();
        T item = it.next();
        if (predicate.test(item)) {
            // We found it, return the index
            return index;
        }
    }
    // We didn't find anything
    return -1;
}
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("foo");
    list.add("bar");
    list.add("foobar");
    list.add("fubar");
    list.add("Hello World!");
    System.out.printf("String with length %s has index %s%n",
            5, getObjectIndexFromList(list, s -> s.length() == 5));
}
```

And the output:

> String with length 5 has index 3

Comment: I preconize the second solution because it's more optimal. But I just want to know why `a -> a.equals(tmpA)` returns -1 even after overriding `Equals()` and `HashCode()` methods

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing all the code in an executable example. Are you sure that all fields checked in `equals` are indeed equal?

Comment: I am logging the item.getFieldA() and its value is equal

Comment: Run it with your debugger and see which line is causing equals to return false, should put you on the correct track

Answer (score 0):

If you have override hashcode and equals methods... why don't you make a plain call to 'List.indexOf'?

Make them extend the same abstract class (I don't know the exact problem, but if they have end in the same List is highly probable that they will end being family) and use it.

IndexOf uses 'equals' to find the index of the object so it must work...

Comment: The problem isn't in the algorithm of how to find the item index but how to pass a different type of list and item each time I need to call this method.